# How to change textbox value by selecting suggested value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a Desktop App in Visual Studio With C#.
I've a String array  called Tag_Word_Box.  In a textbox if I type something, then it will be show suggest words from Tag_Word_Box array.

In briefly, assume that- I've 5 words respectively [aabc] [abc] [abd] [abcg] [bcd] If I type in textbox only 'a' then it will be  show all of words without 'bcd'.
If I select 'aabc' or press enter one of suggesting words, then- it will be assign whole word in textbox, that means textbox value will be changed with selecting word by 'a'.

BTW, I know that- it will be solved by trie algorithm to find out words. But I want to know that how to do that operation in visual studio respect of C#  that-

**1. to show suggesting words when I type something**

**2. and how do I change textbox value by selecting from those?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Please include the tag for UI framework you are using (e.g., Winforms, WPF, UWP), and the code that you have tried that has not worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All textboxs have an 'AutoCompleteSource' property. Set it to CustomSource from the Properties toolbar. Then set the 'AutoCompleteMode' property to SuggestAppend. Now, in the code, add this to the TextChanged Event of the textbox:

```
    var autocomplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autocomplete.AddRange(Tag_Word_Box);
    textBoxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocomplete;
```

To do the complete thing in code, add this to the TextChanged event of your textbox:

```
    textBoxName.AutoCompleteSource=AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBoxName.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    var autocomplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autocomplete.AddRange(Tag_Word_Box);
    textBoxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocomplete;
```

> Remember to replace textBoxName by the name of your textbox before using this code.